# Audio dies a couple of seconds after runing sudo alsa force-reload

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

On boot, my computer running Ubuntu 18.04 does not play any audio, excluding some system sounds. However, if I run the command `sudo alsa force-reload`, the audio works for a couple of seconds, but then rapidly dies off while becoming distorted, quickly resulting in no audio again. Running `sudo alsa force-reload` again causes this to repeat.

How can I get my audio to work steadily?

Edit 1: 
Most people with simmilar issues online seem to have fixed them by reinstalling `alsa` and `pulseaudio`, or by clearing some config files. I have tried both and neither works.

Comment: Is there something suspicious in your kernel `dmesg` logs when audio gets distorted?

Comment: No. At least as far as I can tell. 
I also updated the question with some details on past trials.